# Does $\sum_0^\infty(\frac{1}{9n+1})$ converges?

Tags: convergence-divergence

Does $\sum_0^\infty(\frac{1}{9n+1})$ converges? If yes, then to what?

Comment: Use the comparison test.

Comment: Hint: ${1\over 9n+1}\ge {1\over 18 n}$.

Comment: so it diverges correct??

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesen't converge.
You can see this in several ways.
As David Mitra pointed out you can observe that $\frac1{9n+1}\ge\frac1{18n}$; then you'll have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac1{9n+1}\ge\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac1{18n}=
\frac1{18}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac1{n}=+\infty\;\;.
$$
Another way is to observe that $\frac1{9n+1}\sim_{+\infty}\frac1{9n}$ (in fact $\lim_n\frac{1/(9n+1)}{1/9n}=1)$ hence the two series $\sum\frac{1}{9n+1}$ and $\sum\frac1{9n}$ will have the same type of behaviour, so you can conclude.